# Blank white page in localhost

Tags: reactjs

I am calling a function from frontend to backend, but my frontend page is showing a blank white page. I do not see any errors and suspect it might be a problem in useeeffect,

```
  useEffect(() => {     
    (async () => {       
        setLoading(true)       
        try {         
            const res = await apiConnector("GET", categories.CATEGORIES_API)     
            setSubLinks(res.data.data)       
        } catch (error) {         
            console.log("Could not fetch Categories.", error)       
    }       setLoading(false)
```

Is there anything wrong in useeffect
I am calling a function from frontend to backend but my frontend page is showing blank white page

It is not showing any error but showing blank white page ,

Comment: Could you give more details about your frontend and backend and better format your code?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser (dev tools) console?

Comment: You only do `setLoading(false)` if there's an error. Is this intentional? Without knowing the rest of your code it seems like the loading screen will never stop showing if there are no errors. Perhaps put `setLoading(false)` outside the try catch block at the end.